# Safari on iPad and Windows

Tags: windows, ipad, safari

Just wondering iPad version and windows version of Safari behave the same? If a website is tested on Safari on Windows, do I have to test it on iPad?? Never used iPad before. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely have to, there are some cumbersome issues you may have to solve. Just an example: a scrollable DIV (very common, nowadays) or an old IFRAME (now quite rare) won't scroll, or better, should be scrolled using two fingers instead of one, and no iPad user know that. Sensitive web designers avoid scrollable sub-elements when serving a page to an iPad/iPhone user.

More, even the newest iPad hardware is slow and sluggish *if compared to your computer*, so you better see how your website loads, and not only how it looks.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Another difference is that on touch devices, there's no "mouse over" events. This caused many javascript codes to behave differently on iPad/iPhones. You should definitely buy an iPad and test it.

Comment: Good point Yuji, but however sensitive web designers don't do "mouse over" for critical features (ie. you should not open a submenu by mouse over), just for design :)

Answer (score 0):

They basically run the same but the iDevices use a more lighter mobile version of javascript. Layout should be much the same though.
Testing is always a good idea though.